# Is using getline() in a while loop bad practice?

Tags: c, while-loop, getline

If I have a file which contains a `'\n'` on virtually every line, and I use `getline()` in a `while` loop to read the content, is this bad practice?
My understanding is that `getline()` will be called numerous times for each `'\n'` char reached, and so `realloc()` will be called each time also. Which seems inefficient?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to open file: ");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t characters;

    while ((characters = getline(&buffer, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        fputs(buffer, stdout);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is vague and broad. Whether any particular function should be used depends on the purposes and the available alternatives, among other factors. Stack Overflow is not a general tutorial service to be used for guidance about general coding practices. It is for specific narrow questions, not vague and broad questions.

Comment: @rain, a singular downsize to `getline()` is that it is not part of the C standard library, yet   available on many implementations.

Comment: @rain: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem calling `getline` in a loop as you do. As a matter of fact, this exactly the intended use case and used in the example in the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

`realloc` is only called if the array allocated so far is too short for the current line, thus it will be called very little and you can even lower the number of calls by allocating an initial array and set its length in the `len` variable.

Since `getline` returns the number of characters read, you could write the line using `fwrite` instead of `fputs`.  Note however that the behavior is subtly different: `fwrite` will output lines read from the file containing embedded null bytes, whereas `fputs` would stop on the first null byte. This is usually not an issue as text files usually do not contain null bytes.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s: %s\n",
                "file.txt", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t characters;

#if 1
    // optional code to show how to start with a preallocated buffer
    if ((buffer = malloc(256)) != NULL)
        len = 256; 
#endif

    while ((characters = getline(&buffer, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        fwrite(buffer, 1, characters, stdout);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good point about "you can even lower the number of calls by allocating an initial array and set its length".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: sharp eyes as always :) I updated the answer with an explanation regarding the embedded null bytes and how to preallocate the `buffer`.

Comment: "text files are not supposed to contain null bytes" --> null bytes are certainly _uncommon_, yet I would not say _not supposed to_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: null bytes in text files is a recipe for failure.

Comment: Robust code does not rely on a text file adhering to some format, like lack of _null bytes_ or no exceptionally long lines, or lacking a final `'\n'`, etc.  Code failing to cope with such problems is the recipe for failure.  Code that fails on (and not detects) bad input becomes a hacker exploit.  Input data is evil.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: While I agree with your assessment, most C string functions are inadequate to handle lines with embedded null bytes, making it difficult to handle such contents easily.  Depending on the use case, this might be worthwhile (for example qemacs does handle any file contents and will religiously preserve null bytes if present) but for most text utilities, handling null bytes is just not a requirement and lines with such bytes might just be silently truncated. Allowing hacker exploits is unacceptable in all cases... requiring constant scrutiny and acute awareness in C.